# How to merge/feed two uint8_t buffers?

Tags: c, arduino, esp32, uint8t

Hey sorry for this novice question but I think im just missing something obvious... Would be very happy with the some guidance on this:

---

Inline docu of esp_camera.h:

```
/**
 * @brief Data structure of camera frame buffer
 */
typedef struct {
    uint8_t * buf;              /*!< Pointer to the pixel data */
    size_t len;                 /*!< Length of the buffer in bytes */
    size_t width;               /*!< Width of the buffer in pixels */
    size_t height;              /*!< Height of the buffer in pixels */
    pixformat_t format;         /*!< Format of the pixel data */
} camera_fb_t;
```

plus extract of demo code:
from esp32 code:

```
    //replace this with your own function
    display_image(fb->width, fb->height, fb->pixformat, fb->buf, fb->len);
```

code getting framebuffer

```
    camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
    esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;

    fb = esp_camera_fb_get(); // framebuffer in grayscale
```

---

and feed **fb** buffer into **imagebuffer**

```
    int w, h;
    int i, count;
    uint8_t *imagebuffer = quirc_begin(qr, &w, &h);

    //Feed 'fb' into 'imagebuffer' somehow?
    //-------------------------------
    // ----- DUMMY CODE?! not the proper way? ----
    imagebuffer = fb->buf; //fb's own buf field, holding the pixel data

    //Comment from quirc below:
    /* Fill out the image buffer here.
     * 'imagebuffer' is a pointer to a w*h bytes.
     * One byte per pixel, w pixels per line, h lines in the buffer.
     */
    //
    quirc_end(qr);
```

Inline comment docu of quirc below:

```
    /* These functions are used to process images for QR-code recognition.
     * quirc_begin() must first be called to obtain access to a buffer into
     * which the input image should be placed. Optionally, the current
     * width and height may be returned.
     *
     * After filling the buffer, quirc_end() should be called to process
     * the image for QR-code recognition. The locations and content of each
     * code may be obtained using accessor functions described below.
     */
    uint8_t *quirc_begin(struct quirc *q, int *w, int *h);
    void quirc_end(struct quirc *q);
```

https://github.com/dlbeer/quirc

---

I've looked through the code, source files etc, but as i'm a novice ive no clue how to merge or feed the one into the other.

---

Could anyone point me into the right direction here? Am not dirty of looking through heaps of code but my inexperience with C is the issue here :S Thanks!

Comment: C or C++? Merge what exactly? What should the result be? What is `camera_fb_t `? What should `buf = fb;` represent?

Comment: Tried to clearify it a bit. The whole thing is about getting the data of fb into buf. So as I know they arent simple variables I took the wild guess that just doing buf = fb wouldnt do the job :S

Comment: Look up `memcpy()`

Comment: @yhyrcanus is this what you meant?
`memcpy(imagebuffer, fb->buf, strlen(fb->buf)+1);` 
Is that a correct way of 'feeding' one buffer into another?

Comment: Not the correct way: `invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]` I really feel out of my depth here

Comment: You can't use `strlen()` on a byte buffer containing image data. It's not a string. That's why the structure has a `len` element, use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of the library was kind enough to explain it,
posting the code answer here as it may help others:

```
  int w, h;
  int i, count;
  uint8_t *buff = quirc_begin(qr, &w, &h);
  //
  int total_pixels = w * h;

  for (int i = 0; i < total_pixels; i++) {
    // grab a pixel from your source image at element i
    // convert it somehow, then store it
    buff[i] = fb->buf[i]; //?
  }
  //
  quirc_end(qr);

  count = quirc_count(qr);
  Serial.println("count found codes:");
  Serial.println(count);
```

[github issue with lib author's explaination](https://github.com/dlbeer/quirc/issues/66)

Comment: To clarify my ambiguous comment :) : you can replace the loop with `memcpy(buff,fb->buf,total_pixels);`  I wonder if instead of calculating total_pixels, if you could just use `fb->len`. Not sure if that gets set anywhere in the process.

Comment: Will check it out, the code above works but there's always room for improvement :D